# Could not get unknown property '$projectDir' for main resources of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

#### Environment

OS : m1 mac
IDE : Intellij
Java Version : 17

#### directory structure

src
- main
- frontend : this is create-react-app frontend
- src
- pages
index.js
- java

#### build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
   main {
      resources { srcDirs = [$projectDir/src/main/resources]}
   }
}
```

#### Error message

```
Could not get unknown property '$projectDir' for main resources of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.
```

I want to use '$projectDir' in build.gradle !
And I'll fix warning src `import component outside src/ directory`
Is there any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should just double-quote the `$projectDir/src/main/resources` path so that you `build.gradle` snipper looks like this:

```
sourceSets {
   main {
      resources { srcDirs = ["$projectDir/src/main/resources"]}
   }
}
```

##### A bit of background

Now, this path string is interpolated with the Gradle `projectDir` variable. String interpolation is when you can use variables in a string to have that string sort of dynamically built at runtime. For that, you have to reference a variable with the the `$` (dollar sign) in front of the variable name.

Also, the error message is quite clear about the issue. Without the quotes, the `$projectDir` becomes a "property" of "main resources of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet". And that variable is evidently missing from that `DefaultSourceDirectorySet`.

Comment: Let me try it !! Thank you so much for your kind and quick answer :)